# VPN wont save after reinstalling Network Manager

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I am a newer Ubuntu 20.04 user. I accidentally deleted Network Manager. I reinstalled it realizing what I had done and everything is back to normal, except I cannot save a vpn in the settings to connect to my Nord VPN. The VPN setting in the drop down menu no longer exists. When I go into the actual settings and manually add the VPN it wont finalize and save the VPN for use, it just disappears...

If anyone can help me get my VPN ability back I'd appreciate it lol.

Comment: I have connected my VPN through the terminal, but I lost the convenience of being able to toggle my VPN in the drop down menu in the top right hand part of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If it uses openvpn, maybe try
`sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome`
in the terminal.

Comment: I already tried that unfortunately. It doesn't seem to help. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what actually broke was the GNOME shell. Directions linked below.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa